# more complicated label in checkbox - Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here's my simple code:

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="rodo"
  label="I agree to Privacy Policy (show more)"
  :rules="policyRules"
  required
></v-checkbox>
```

I want to have simple code inside the label, just something to show more on click. What's the best way to approach that? I want to have something like that in label:

```
I agree to Privacy Policy 
<span @click="showMore=!showMore">(show more)</span> 
<span v-show="showMore">Lorem ipsum...</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the label slot.

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="rodo"
  :rules="policyRules"
  required>
  <template v-slot:label>
   I agree to Privacy Policy 
   <span @click="showMore=!showMore">(show more)</span> 
   <span v-show="showMore">Lorem ipsum...</span>
  </template>
</v-checkbox>
```

See also documentation for more information:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using vuetify I think you can easily append an icon and click on that:

```
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="rodo"
        label="I agree to Privacy Policy"
        append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
        required
        @click:append="showMore = !showMore"
      ></v-checkbox>
      <span v-if="showMore">{{ policyRules }}</span>
```

[image]